# C#, Is there same thing to the WaitForInputIdle() of redirected process for a console app?

Tags: c#

The redirected process is a console app without a user interface.
C# requests process has user interface to use `WaitForInputIdle()`.

While the input is busy, I can't send text to the input.

Comment: Send by another thread.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others, which shows that you cannot send any text to the input you have.